# makefile that makes executable for each file in a folder

Tags: c++, makefile

Below is a makefile. Please refer to the section where %.c is the target, and one of the dependencies is a .psvn file. I would like this make file to go through every psvn file and generate a .c file for it. How would I change the makefile to do this?

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
OPT = -g -Wall -O3 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -std=c++11
PSVNOPT = --no_state_map --no_abstraction --backwards_moves --history_len=0

psvn2c_core.c:
    cp ../psvn2c_core.c ./psvn2c_core.c

psvn2c_state_map.c:
    cp ../psvn2c_state_map.c ./psvn2c_state_map.c

psvn2c_abstraction.c:
    cp ../psvn2c_abstraction.c ./psvn2c_abstraction.c

%.c: %.psvn  psvn2c_core.c psvn2c_state_map.c psvn2c_abstraction.c
    ../psvn2c  $(PSVNOPT) --name=$(*F)  < $< > $@
    rm -f ./psvn2c_core.c ./psvn2c_state_map.c ./psvn2c_abstraction.c

.PRECIOUS: %.c

%.succ: %.c succ.c
    $(CC) $(OPT) succ.c -include $< -o $@

%.run: %.c run.cpp Node.cpp distribution.cpp
    $(CXX) $(OPT) run.cpp Node.cpp distribution.cpp -include $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f *.run *.o psvn2c_core.c psvn2c_state_map.c psvn2c_abstraction.c
```

Comment: Make this specific rule a template applied for subfolders only.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this BEFORE the first target (`psvn2c_core.c:`):

```
PSVN_FILES := $(wildcard *.psvn)
C_FILES := $(patsubst %.psvn,%.c,$(PSVN_FILES))

all: $(C_FILES)
```

Done.  When `make all` (or `make` since `all` will be the default target since it appears first in the makefile) is invoked, it will try to build all the `.c` files.